Adjustable swicth box caused internal drywal crack (face intact). Best remedy?
I used an adjustable switch box on a project, and now realize I should have taken some precautions to avoid problems when the drywall was applied. Note, this is a small section of wall, with a door in it, and the switch will just a few inches from the casing, when I reinstall it.
I didn't notch the stud, so the bracket plate that wraps the front of the stud is obviously a little proud of the rest of the stud. I did properly attach the bracket on the front and sides with drywall screws.
I also shouldn't have screwed the drywall to the stud too close to the bracket, but I did; like maybe 4" below it.
After a few days, in which I finished joints and covered screw heads, I notice the drywall had cracked internally at one corner of the box (the corner with the screw that placed too close to the bracket). The face (paper) is not cracked.
I just pulled out a bunch of screws and my switches, recessed the box using its adjustment screw, and managed to insert a couple of pieces of drywall shim behind the drywall that was flush to the stud, just below the bracket. Then I reinstalled that drywall screw (plus all the others). So now the two sides of that internal crack are basically flush with each other.
For sturdiness, I was thinking of getting a Strait Flex drywall patch and mudding out from the box with setting compound, to provide some extra stability. Given that there's a minor hump where the bracket is, I was even thinking of skimming the entire wall. What I don't want to do is pull out this (brand new) piece of drywall after doing joints, etc.
Is there anything else I should think of doing where that crack is? Would there be any major benefit, say, in cutting the face, removing any loose gypsum, and filling with setting compound, before applying the patch and finishing? Any other secret tips for strengthening or fixing a crack inside a sheet of drywall, like trying to inject some kind of glue? :shrug:
Thanks

Is there anything else I should think of doing where that crack is? ... I don't see a crack

@jsotola, are you asking for a picture, or saying that if you don't see the crack, it's not a crack? There's a crack in the gypsum, not the face. You can still feel it a bit.

Is this just an issue for your OCD?

No, or I wouldn't be asking. Yes, I'm OCD, but also, I don't want this looking crappy when I paint it, or moving around over time.

Pictures would help.

There isn't much to see since I shimmed it, but I'll see if I can capture something and post it

I got feedback in another forum, so moving on. I'm going to try injecting some hot mud into the crack, and if that doesn't work or seems inadequate, cut the face, clean out, fill with hot mud, then tape/patch and finish.
In the future, I think I'd notch the stud to get the plate flush, if I ever use one of these boxes again.
Same for stud guards to protect wiring. This would just make things easier for someone like me, who's a pretty lousy drywall finisher as-is.
